# Nested loops with list and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a html ul li from which i need to grab the content and update with other content situated in an array. So far i create the nested loop but i always get stuck at the same point: Each li get ineterated 4 times (my array is long 4) endend up display just the last element of my array
My code would be more clear then me:

**Html**

```
<div class="menu-sidebar">
<ul>
<li><a>Batman</a></li>
<li><a>Billo</a></li>
<li><a>Breaking-</a></li>
<li><a>Buttons</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
   var currentNames = [];
    var newListName = [
    "Hello",
    "Billo M",
    "Breaking Hard",
    "Button"
    ];

    $(".menu-sidebar li a").each(function(index) {
        var listName = $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,'');
        currentNames.push(listName);
    //console.log(currentNames); //["Batman", "Billo", "Breaking-", "Buttons", .. ]
    //console.log(newListName); //["hello", "Billo M", "Breaking Hard", "Button"]
    });

    for (var j = 0; j < currentNames.length; j++) {
            var currentName = currentNames[j]

        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            console.log(currentNames[j]); 
            console.log(newListName[j]);

            $(".menu-sidebar li a").each(function(index) {
                $(this).text(newListName[j]);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't see the point of your inner loop. it goes from `0` to `<1` ... so once. It's not a loop if it only executes once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesnt seem to be much point doing multiple passes over the list, just one will do (if I understand your description correctly)

```
$(".menu-sidebar li a").each(function(index) {
        $(this).text(newListName[index])
});
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var newListName = [
    "Hello",
    "Billo M",
    "Breaking Hard",
    "Button"
    ];

$(".menu-sidebar li a").each(function(index) {
        $(this).text(newListName[index])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-sidebar">
<ul>
<li><a>Batman</a></li>
<li><a>Billo</a></li>
<li><a>Breaking-</a></li>
<li><a>Buttons</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: -.- Omg.. was so simple... that are the moment when one should take a break instead of insiste and lose the mind in the code! haha Thankss @Jamiec!!

Comment: How did this just get a downvote an hour after the OP actually said it helped her, and got marked accepted. SO is weird sometimes!